# Remove '-' symbols when counting down from Java script code

Tags: javascript, html

I a using a script to work out the hours mins and seconds to a date, this is fine for past dates as it continues to count up, however when the date is in the future a - symbol is attached to the front and I don't want this, how do I prevent this from being applied

```
function upTime(countTo) {
      now = new Date();
      difference = (now-countTo);

      days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
      years=Math.floor(days/365);
      hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
      mins=Math.floor(((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
      secs=Math.floor((((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);

      //document.getElementById('years').firstChild.nodeValue = years;

      document.getElementById('live-hour').innerHTML = hours;
      document.getElementById('live-min').innerHTML = mins;
      document.getElementById('live-sec').innerHTML = secs;

      clearTimeout(upTime.to);
      upTime.to=setTimeout(function(){ upTime(countTo); },1000);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs

Comment: That would be because I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to get the absolute value of the `difference`.

```
difference = Math.abs(now-countTo);
```